# Wired connection taking precedence of wireless

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, debian

I have wired together two Linux machines. One machine has a wireless connection to my router whilst the other machine does not. The machine without wireless access (PC1) is configured such that it has a unique static IP and the other machine (PC2) is set as its default gateway. PC2 is configured such that it also has a unique IP and uses the router as a default gateway. When I enable the wired connection PC1 can communicate with PC2's eth0 and wlan0 interfaces, and PC2 can communicate with PC1. Unfortunately when the wired connection is enabled PC2 cannot communicate with the router and thus, neither can PC1. Essentially PC2 wired and wireless connections can't operate at the same time.

PC2 (NOTE: `route-n` is the same regardless of the wired being enabled or not)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7a:fe:97:99  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:a4:4c:62:ee:86  
          inet addr:10.0.0.140  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::62a4:4cff:fe62:ee86/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12554 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:1509568 (1.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2179347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2179347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:217854881 (217.8 MB)  TX bytes:217854881 (217.8 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:4a:00:66:58:98  
          inet addr:10.0.0.103  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c24a:ff:fe66:5898/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1605422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:669649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1405768536 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:83997471 (83.9 MB)
```

PC1 (NOTE: I am unable to retrieve the ifconfig of PC1)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.139      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Superuser. Can you add the output of `ifconfig` and `route -n` for both PC1 and PC2 and also the IP and subnet mask for the router onto your post.

Comment: Further to @MarkoPolo's comment, would you include separate `route -n` outputs for when the wired connection is disabled and enabled?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that PC2 can access the internet with this configuration: I would have expected the router's address to be the gateway, and this would normally be `192.160.0.1` or `192.168.0.254`. Plus, your statements "When I enable the wired connection PC1 can communicate with PC2's eth0 and wlan0 interfaces" and "when the wired connection is enabled PC2 cannot communicate with the router" seem contradictory. In what sense does PC1 communicate with the wireless interface?

Comment: The IP of my router is 10.0.0.138. This is because it is a cheap Technicolor router made in Vietnam. When I ping the address of wlan0 from PC1 there is a response however, when I ping the router from PC2 I get `destination host unreachable`. Disabling wired resolves this issue but obviously severs the link between PC1 and PC2.

Comment: I think your problem is with how bridging is set up. Internet connection sharing may dedicate the gateway to the wired network, cutting off the PC where ICS is enabled. This certainly happens in Windows, but it is some time since I did it in Linux, and I can't recall whether the sharing computer had internet access while sharing was enabled.

Comment: Your easiest solution may be to work round the problem by buying a cheap USB wireless dongle for PC1. It will slow communications between the PCs, but you will get full connectivity.

Comment: @AFH I have only got 2 USB ports on PC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current setup of the PC2 routing table is your problem.  I've reproduced it here with unimportant columns removed and converted from netmask to CIDR notation:

```
Destination     Gateway         Metric Iface
0.0.0.0/0       10.0.0.138      0      wlan0
10.0.0.0/24     0.0.0.0         1      eth0
10.0.0.0/24     0.0.0.0         9      wlan0
```

The first row means in plain English "Traffic to all other sites is sent through the 10.0.0.138 gateway".

The second and third row provide the same destination, so the lower metric wins.  Row 3 might as well not even be there.  Meaning in plain English "To reach the gateway 10.0.0.138 and all other 10.0.0.* peers, send through eth0"

Together this results in traffic destined to the Internet going through eth0, hence your lack of connectivity.

The problem arises because you have the same subnet used on two different bridging domains in the same network, which is not allowed.  Stop that!

Change the netmask of PC2's eth0 interface to 255.255.252.0 and give it an IP address farther from the router's, which will change the routing table to (for example giving PC2 eth0 10.0.0.21 and PC1 eth0 10.0.0.22)

```
Destination     Gateway         Metric Iface
0.0.0.0/0       10.0.0.138      0      wlan0
10.0.0.20/30    0.0.0.0         1      eth0
10.0.0.0/24     0.0.0.0         9      wlan0
```

Now traffic to the gateway 10.0.0.138 won't match the second row at all, and will use the third row correctly.

Even better would be to use a non-overlapping range for the wired connection, for example 10.0.1.x

In order to get internet access working for PC1 also, your router will need to send traffic destined for PC1 via PC2.  There are two ways to set this up: change the router's routing table, or configure PC2 to perform proxy-ARP.

Comment: Can you recommend any good proxy-ARP guides?

Comment: Is the internet connection on PC2 working again?

Comment: Yes. Everything works except PC1 cannot connect to the internet or ping the router.

Comment: There's a guide at http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.bridging.proxy-arp.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I think could be causing you issues:

1. You state that PC1 is using PC2 as its default gateway, however the routing table from PC1 infact shows `10.0.0.139` as the default gateway, rather than the eth0 interface of PC2 `10.0.0.140`
2. If PC2 is responsible for routing traffic from PC1, have you turned on IP forwarding on PC2? I do not believe this is enabled by default in Linux. Check with `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. If it's 0, the PC2 will drop all routable traffic sent to it by PC1. [Guide if you need to turn it on](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux).
3. If ip forwarding is indeed enabled on PC2, has iptables been configured to accept traffic that hits its forward chain? `iptables -nvL` to check the rules for the Forward chain.